# Frontend Maven Plugin fails on grunt task compass on Bamboo CI Server

Tags: maven, gruntjs, bamboo, compass

I ran Maven locally with Frontend Maven Plugin on a project and it was building successfully. But when committing it to SVN and runnning the build plan on a bamboo server the build failed at the point where grunt wants to begin with the compass task:
[Bamboo Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf7xQ.png)

It seems that bamboo cannot find compass, even though Ruby, Sass und Compass have been installed on bamboo and the path to Ruby was added to the PATH-environment-variable. If I delete the compass task from the Gruntfile, the Build is done successfully on bamboo so that I don't think it is a grunt or node.js issue. 
Has anyone experienced the same and has an idea what I could do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happening when compass is not properly installed. Make sure you have also Ruby gems installed: https://rubygems.org/ and compass too with: `sudo gem install compass`.

You can check if your compass is installed, try running `compass version` in Bamboo script task to check the output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I once again checked the installation and it seems to be properly installed: Compass (1.0.3); Installed at: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0. It was also installed with the 'gem install compass' command in admin-mode (OS of bamboo is Windows).

Comment: In your question I see you added Ruby into PATH variable. Is it Ruby folder only or 'bin' folder too? - "C:/Ruby22-x64/bin"

Comment: I checked it, in the PATH-Variable it is "C:/Ruby22-x64/bin". I also tried to un- and reinstall compass with 'gem uninstall compass' and 'gem uninstall sass' and then 'gem install compass' and when running compass --version it seems to be properly installed but it  is not still found during the build.

Comment: Okay. I suppose you are using "grunt-contrib-compass" plugin. Is it installed before the build (it should be included in package.json and you should run 'npm install') and loaded in grunt file?

Comment: Yes right, it is grunt-contrib-compass and I added it with 'npm install grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev' to package.json. Also it is loaded in Gruntfile.js. Locally the maven build is working well, only on bamboo it fails.